# Prevent soft input from appearing

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, barcode-scanner

I have a Bluetooth barcode scanner attached to Android tablet. Hardware keyboard is disabled in Android setting. This allows me both scanning barcodes and using soft keyboard for typing.

When I scan a barcode, my activity catches all keys as expected. But the soft keyboard appears.

How to prevent the soft keyboard from appearing?

I have tried the followings:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode=stateHidden
```

or

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

(or `stateAlwaysHidden`),

but nothing worked. When the app catches hardware keydown, the soft keyboard appears.

Comment: Try using dispatchTouchEvent

Comment: @ashishdhiman2007 , this code just disables any touch interaction with the app.

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest, would you please try the following

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".Main"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
```

Comment: Thank you. As I wrote in my question, this does not help. The soft keyboard is displayed when a barcode is scanned.

Answer (score 0):

please add this attribute to your `activity` in the manifest :

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is a duplicate of Alok Gupta answer.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
public static void hideSoftInput(Activity activity) {
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view == null) view = new View(activity);
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This code hides the keyboard after it appears. I want to prevent the appearance at all.